# How to convert a timestamp value fetched from ResultSet to JSON Object?

Tags: java, json, heroku, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey (JAX-RS) & I have the following class **Post.java**

```
public class Post {

    private String data;
    private Long time;

    public Post() {
        data = null;
        time = null;
    }

    public Post(final String data, final Long time) {
        this.data = data;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setData(final String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setDate(final Long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

and the class **PostBundle.java**

```
import java.util.List;

public class PostBundle {

    private String statusCode;
    private String message;
    private List<Post> posts;

    public PostBundle() {
        statusCode = null;
        message = null;
        posts = null;
    }

    public PostBundle(final String statusCode, final String message, final List<Post> posts) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.message = message;
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(final String statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public void setMessage(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setPosts(final List<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

}
```

I have a database in Heroku from which I'm trying to fetch the values of a `timestamp` column with the following code: -

```
final String sqlCheckWallPost = 
                "SELECT user_post, post_time FROM wall_post WHERE user_id = ?;";

        preparedStatement = null;
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlCheckWallPost);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);

        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if  (resultSet.next()) {
            posts.add(new Post(
                    resultSet.getString("user_post"),
                    Long.valueOf(resultSet.getTime("post_time").getTime())));
            while   (resultSet.next()) {
                posts.add(new Post(
                        resultSet.getString("user_post"), 
                        Long.valueOf(resultSet.getTime("post_time").getTime())));                       
            }
            postBundle = new PostBundle("200", "OK", posts);
```

The code above is a part of an API that takes in POST requests and produces `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`

But whenever I make a POST request to it, it returns a JSON array, but it does't return anything for the `time` part of **Post** objects.

I end up getting this:

```
{"message":"OK","posts":[{"data":"blah blah"},{"data":"someum la deh!!"},{"data":"someum la deh!!"},{"data":"someum la deh!!"},{"data":"someum la deh!!"},{"data":"someum la deh!!"},{"data":"someum la deh!!"},{"data":"someum la deh!!"},{"data":"someum la deh!!"},{"data":"WHADDUP DAWG"},{"data":"WHADDUP DAWG!!!"},{"data":"TEST"},{"data":"HEY THERE!!"},{"data":"HEY THERE!!"},{"data":"HEY THERE!!"},{"data":"HEY THERE 12!!"}],"statusCode":"200"}
```

If you look at the response above, it doesn't contain anything for the time part, it doesn't even mention the key. What's going wrong here? I know that the following always results in `timestamp` values:

```
posts.add(new Post(
                            resultSet.getString("user_post"),
                            Long.valueOf(resultSet.getTime("post_time").getTime())));
```

because when I fetch only the `timestamp` value and return only `Long` as `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`, it does show the time in ms. However, for JSON, it doesn't.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with JDBC or postgresql; I'd expect you to get the exact same problem if you set just a long value.

Comment: So what is the solution to it?

Comment: How do you serialize the PostBundle to JSON?